# c++ forward declaration and incomplete type

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

Hello I have trouble working with forward declaration. I can't access the forwarded class function, though I need to do so.

Here is my Window.h:

```
#include "Tab.h"  // Needed because Window will create new Tabs

class Window {
  public:
    ...
    void doSome();

};
```

Here is Tab.h:

```
class Window;  // forward delcaration

class Tab {

public:
  class Tab(Window *parent);
  void callParentFunction();

private:
  Window *m_parent;
};
```

And lastly, Tab.cpp:

```
#include "Tab.h"

Tab::Tab(Window *parent) {
  m_parent = parent;
}

Tab::callParentFunction() {
  m_parent->doSome();  // Error
}
```

The compiler returns me the following error:
    invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Window'

How can I access the parent's function knowing it already includes Tab.h to create tabs? 
If I can't, what do you advise me to do?

Comment: `#include Tab.h` Is that your actual code?

Comment: You mean I made a typo right? Should be #include "Tab.h"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the definition of the `Window` class in order to call

```
 m_parent->doSome();
```

So, include `Window.h` in `Tab.cpp`.

Comment: Wow it works! According to newbie tutorial, I thought including headers in .cpp files was prohibited

Comment: @AlexandreToqué well, you were already including headers in `.cpp` files (for example, `Tab.h` in `Tab.cpp`. Chances are you have misunderstood the tutorial.